# Wikipedia JSON API retrieve page content without links

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xml, json, wikipedia-api

I'm using Wikipedia JSON API and I'm bring to retrieve the page content without the links
for example,

```
https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&format=json&titles=May_21&prop=revisions&rvprop=content&rvsection=1
```

For example:

```
[[293]] &ndash; Roman Emperors [[Diocletian]] and [[Maximian]] appoint [[Galerius]] as [[Caesar (title)|''Caesar'']] to Diocletian, beginning the period of four rulers known as the [[Tetrarchy]].
```

Replace `&ndash` with `-`

`[[Caesar (title)|''Caesar'']]` Should be `Caesar`

I'm using Objective-C

How can I retrieve the same page content, but without the links characters ?

Thanks!

Comment: You should clarify what you mean by links characters. Maybe show an example in your question of what this would look like.

Comment: you should replace them using regular expressions. What language are you using?

Comment: Thanks, I'm using Objective-C, please take a look on my second example, I can't manipulate this kind of text because it may vary

Comment: What do you want to do with templates?

Comment: For the clearness, is the any way to retrieve the page content as a plain text without any links & titles characters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

that should it be :-)

```
NSString * stringToParse = @"{\"query\":{\"normalized\":[{\"from\":\"May_21\",\"to\":\"May 21\"}],\"pages\":{\"19684\":{\"pageid\":19684,\"ns\":0,\"title\":\"May 21\",\"revisions\":[{\"*\":\"==Events==\\n* [[293]] &ndash; Roman Emperors [[Diocletian]] and [[Maximian]] appoint [[Galerius]] as [[Caesar (title)|''Caesar'']] to Diocletian, beginning the period of four rulers known as the [[Tetrarchy]].\\n* [[878]] &ndash; [[Syracuse, Italy]], is [[Muslim conquest of Sicily|captured]] by the ...";

//Replace &ndash with -
stringToParse = [stringToParse stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"&ndash" withString:@"-"];

//[[Caesar (title)|''Caesar'']] Should be Caesar
//and [[Maximian]] should be Maximian
//same for [[1972]] -> 1972
NSString *regexToReplaceWikiLinks = @"\\[\\[([A-Za-z0-9_ ()]+?\\|)?(\\'\\')?(.+?)(\\'\\')?\\]\\]";

NSError *error = NULL;
NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:regexToReplaceWikiLinks
                                                                       options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive
                                                                         error:&error];

// attention, the found expression is replacex with the third parenthesis
NSString *modifiedString = [regex stringByReplacingMatchesInString:stringToParse
                                                           options:0
                                                             range:NSMakeRange(0, [stringToParse length])
                                                      withTemplate:@"$3"];

NSLog(@"%@", modifiedString);
```

results in:

```
{"query":{"normalized":[{"from":"May_21","to":"May 21"}],"pages":{"19684":{"pageid":19684,"ns":0,"title":"May 21","revisions":[{"*":"==Events==\n* 293 -; Roman Emperors Diocletian and Maximian appoint Galerius as Caesar to Diocletian, beginning the period of four rulers known as the Tetrarchy.\n* 878 -; Syracuse, Italy, is captured by the ...
```

Answer (score 2):

Use a HTML to text converter (e. g. [links](http://www.jikos.cz/~mikulas/links/) or some browser simulator such as [PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org/)). Way less painful than converting the wikitext to text, in which case you would have to deal with templates.

Comment: ...not only templates, but the whole wiki markup is awful to "parse".

Comment: maybe, but it doesn't solve the problem, sometimes you have to use what u have...

Answer (score 0):

[Regular expressions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) are the way to go to solve this one; Here's an example using JavaScript (but you could apply the same solution to any language with regular expressions);

```js
<dl>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        var source = "[[293]] &ndash; Roman Emperors [[Diocletian]] and [[Maximian]] appoint [[Galerius]] as [[Caesar (title)|''Caesar'']] to Diocletian, beginning the period of four rulers known as the [[Tetrarchy]].";

        document.writeln('<dt> Original </dt>');
        document.writeln('<dd>' + source + '</dd>');

        // Replace links with any found titles
        var matchTitles = /\[\[([^\]]+?)\|\'\'(.+?)\'\']\]/ig; /* <- Answer */
        source = source.replace(matchTitles, '$2');

        document.writeln('<dt> First Pass </dt>');
        document.writeln('<dd style="color: green;">' + source + '</dd>');

        // Replace links with contents
        var matchLinks = /\[\[(.+?)\]\]/ig;
        source = source.replace(matchLinks, '$1');

        document.writeln('<dt> Second Pass </dt>');
        document.writeln('<dd>' + source + '</dd>');
    </script>
</dl>
```

You can also see this working here: http://jsfiddle.net/NujmB/

Answer (score 0):

*I dont know objective C but here's the code in javascript that I am using for same purpose* 
(It can work as psedo code to you and help other users from javascript)

```
 var url = 'http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?callback=?&action=parse&page=facebook&prop=text&format=json&section=0';
     // Section = 0 for taking first section of wiki page i.e. introduction only     
            $.getJSON(url,function(response){
                // Taking only the first paragraph from introduction
                var intro = $(response.parse.text['*']).filter('p:eq(0)').html();
                var wikiBox = $('#wikipediaBox .wikipedia div.overview');
                wikiBox.empty().html(intro);
                // Converting relative links into absolute ones and links into outer links
                wikiBox.find("a:not(.references a)").attr("href", function(){ return "http://www.wikipedia.org" + $(this).attr("href");});
                wikiBox.find("a").attr("target", "_blank");
                // Removing edits markers
                wikiBox.find('sup.reference').remove(); 
            });
```